# Existence of $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable function in neighbourhood of $0$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I have a problem with the following:

Is there any $\mathbb{C}$-differentiable function in neighbourhood of $0$ such that

a) $f(1/n)=(-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$ for $n=1,2,\dots$

b) $f(1/n)=\frac{1}{n^2-1}$ for $n=2,3,\dots$

c) $|f(1/n)|\le e^{-n}$, and there is a point at which $f$ is not $0$.

I completely dont have idea how can i tackle such problems. Thank you for any help. I need it asap... Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**

Because of continuity it must be $f(0)=0.$

Now, in the first case, you have $$f'(0)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f\left(\frac 1n\right)}{\frac 1n}=\lim_{n\to \infty} nf\left(\frac 1n\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty} (-1)^n.$$ What can you say about $f'(0)?$

In the second case, write $f(1/n)=\frac{1}{n^2-1}=\frac{1/n^2}{1-1/n^2}.$ Can you get a holomorphic function from this?

To the third case assume that $f$ is not identically zero in a neighbourhood of $0.$ So we can write $f(z)=z^mg(z)$ for some positive integer $m$ and a holomorphic function $g$ with $g(0)\ne 0.$ Now, we have

$$\frac{1}{n^m}\left|g\left(\frac 1n\right)\right|=\left|f\left(\frac 1n\right)\right|\le e^{-n},$$ from where

$$\left|g\left(\frac 1n\right)\right|\le n^m e^{-n}.$$  The limit of the LHS is $|g(0)|>0.$ What is the limit of the RHS? Is this possible?

Comment: it can't be differentiable at $0$ because that limit doesn't exist. So also $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$ where $h$ is comples, doesnt exist, yes?

Comment: Write $z=1/n$ to get $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{1-z^2}.$ Is this a solution?

Comment: Yes, since it is a division of holomorfic functions?

Comment: Yes, both holomorphic and the denominator doesn't vanish in neighbourhood of $0.$

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea about the 3rd one?

Comment: I'm working on it.

Comment: I have posted a hint for the third case.